# docker : can't mount some directory from host

Tags: docker, centos

I have the latest centos image for docker and the host machine is ubuntu.

i'm having some script at my host machine, with the path:

```
/home/username/untitled1/preReq.sh
```

i'm trying to execute this script, inside my centos docker.
while i'm mounting the directory of the script, i can't see anything and it appears that i'm mounting the root directory.

i'm using this command (from ~)

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${PWD}:/untitled1  centos
```

someone know how to fix it?

Comment: I deleted my previous answer since it doesn't apply to your situation. What does `echo ${PWD}` output? And what does `docker run --rm -v ${PWD}:/untitled1 centos ls -l /untitled1` and `ls -l ${PWD}` output?

Answer (score 0):

either use the `pwd` command (without caps) if you're in the directory:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${pwd}:/untitled1  centos
```

or use `$HOME` environment variable if you're running with that user:

```
docker run --rm -it -v ${HOME}:/untitled1  centos
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
docker run --rm -it -v `pwd`:/untitled1 centos
```

At least that works for me.

```
${X}
```

evaluates the environment variable `X`. `PWD` is typically set by your shell:

```
$ export
[...]
declare -x PWD="/home/user"
[...]
```

`pwd` on the other hand is a program producing the current working directory to STDOUT:

```
$ whereis pwd
pwd: /bin/pwd /usr/include/pwd.h /usr/share/man/man1/pwd.1.gz
$ pwd
/home/user
```

With the previous docker command the program is executed and its STDOUT is inserted producing:

```
docker run --rm -it -v /home/user:/untitled1 centos
```